# Center images in a div and always place them next to eachother

Tags: html, css

I'm making a website for a friend, and I have a problem with centering images. I want them to be centered both horizontally and vertically, and place them all next to each other, and if the screen is too small for the images, resize them.

What I want:

[image]

What it looks like right now:

[image]

```
<div id="mainbox">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/s3o9yEA.png">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/s3o9yEA.png">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/s3o9yEA.png">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/s3o9yEA.png">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/s3o9yEA.png">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/s3o9yEA.png">
</div>

#mainbox {
    position: absolute;
    top: 70px;
    width: 90%;
    height: 80%;
    border-top: 1px solid #3e3e3e;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #3e3e3e;
    left: 5%;
    max-width: 100%;
    right: 5%;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/whtc4chq/

I have tried a lot of things but they don't seem to work, any advice is appreciated.

Comment: You have to work with `#mainbox img` to center them.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/absolute-center-vertical-horizontal-an-image/  Plus this one's been asked a bunch of times on SO.  Search around, lots of answers.

Comment: Yes I know, sadly, I didn't manage. I removed any code inside `#mainbox img` because it was incorrect, which is why it's not inside the JSFiddle. @ManojKumar

Answer (score 0):

You can use a table instead

```css
#mainbox {
 position: absolute;
 top: 70px;
 width: 90%;
 height: 80%;
 border-top: 1px solid #3e3e3e;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #3e3e3e;
 left: 5%;
        max-width: 100%;
 right: 5%;
}
```

```html
<table id="mainbox">
    <tr>
        <td><img src="http://i.imgur.com/s3o9yEA.png" /></td>
        <td><img src="http://i.imgur.com/s3o9yEA.png" /></td>
        <td><img src="http://i.imgur.com/s3o9yEA.png" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><img src="http://i.imgur.com/s3o9yEA.png" /></td>
        <td><img src="http://i.imgur.com/s3o9yEA.png" /></td>
        <td><img src="http://i.imgur.com/s3o9yEA.png" /></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: While technically this will work, I wouldn't recommend using tables in this day and age.

Answer (score 0):

I managed myself. http://jsfiddle.net/whtc4chq/4/

To center images create a table and to always make them fit, set a max size:

CSS

```
#mainbox {
position: absolute;
top: 70px;
width: 90%;
height: 80%;
border-top: 1px solid #3e3e3e;
border-bottom: 1px solid #3e3e3e;
left: 5%;
right: 5%;
}
#wrapper {
height:100%;
width: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
}

#wrapper td {
vertical-align: middle;
text-align: center;
}

#wrapper td img {
max-width:100%;
max-height: auto;
}
```

HTML

```
    <div id="mainbox">
    <table id="wrapper">
        <tr>
    <td><img src="http://i.imgur.com/s3o9yEA.png" /></td>
    <td><img src="http://i.imgur.com/s3o9yEA.png" /></td>
    <td><img src="http://i.imgur.com/s3o9yEA.png" /></td>
    <td><img src="http://i.imgur.com/s3o9yEA.png" /></td>
    <td><img src="http://i.imgur.com/s3o9yEA.png" /></td>
    <td><img src="http://i.imgur.com/s3o9yEA.png" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```